# What is the best site for questions about telegraphy?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have (actually a couple of) questions about telegraphs. Would this be best on *[Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)*, or [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: I would recommend History first, as the other two sites specialize in technical aspects

Comment: Can you tell us more about the nature of your questions? What do you want to ask, specifically? Please [edit] your question to include a summary/sketch of the questions you want to ask.

Comment: Only physical (wired) telegraphs? For [RF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency) telegraphy, *[Amateur Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tour)* is a candidate. *[Wireless telegraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_telegraphy)*